# ffmpeg help and Krita

Tags: ffmpeg, krita

I was trying to use Krita's video export and I keep getting this error

[[image: The error [1]]

Where should the ffmpeg be?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked he logs files in the output directory yet? Please note I'm not saying that's where "ffmpeg should be" (irrelevant) but rather that those logs may contain some clue about the problem.

Comment: WARNING: library configuration mismatch

Is the only warning I see. I don't know what that means

Comment: You should show the complete log.

Comment: Is this okay? I took a screenshot

Comment: No. The console output is text. You should copy and paste the text instead of making a 250 KB image of text. Images can't be searched, text can't be copied from images, it's harder to read, and the file size is bigger.